# Fix the image in the background of list activity

Tags: android

Hello I have called a image behind the listview and listview is transparent. Each record in the list is appearing on repeating image .  how i can fix this repeat ion of image . Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ac"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"


    >
<TextView  

    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Now i have updated xml files like this 
main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ac"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView" 
    android:background="@drawable/ac"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

List xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"




    >
<TextView  

    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the activity calling in this way

```
{ R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle }
```

the whole code looks like

```
public class Test extends ListActivity  {
      Prefs myprefs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        this.myprefs = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());
        // install handler for processing gui update messages
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("...............");

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("services");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", e.getString("taskid"));
                map.put("pic", "Service name : " + e.getString("employeepic"));
                map.put("serviceinfo", "" +  e.getString("employeename")+ " : "+ e.getString("starttime")
                        +" To " +  e.getString("endtime"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test, 
                        new String[] { "servicename", "serviceinfo" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Is this xml relates to your item Layout and repeatable image is @drawable/ac?

Comment: @woodshy yes  @drawable/ac is the repeatable image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using the above XML to populate the items in the list view (i.e) inside getView() ...


1. Remove `android:background="@drawable/ac"` from the above XML.
2. Add it to the ListView's XML say,

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView" 
    android:background="@drawable/ac"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Explanation:**

Setting Background to the layout that you are using to populate the list will produce *'repeating image'* because you are setting background to the child (i.e) the listView's item and not to the List.

**EDIT:**
1.For your Activity, you will be loading the ListView from an Layout File(say main.xml), inside that layout file for the ListView add the background. 

2. Remove the background from the LinearLayout in your above code.

**Edit Again:**

use the following XML,

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ac"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView" 
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**List xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:background="#00000000"
    >
<TextView  

    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get you . Do you mean to say i have to create another xml file for it or i need to replace with the existing one and thanks for your concern

Comment: its working now list is not getting transparent , I have tried to put this android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in both xml file

Comment: I have updated both the xml file and updated the question , please give a look to it

Comment: thanks a lot its done . You really solved a big problem for me . Once again thanks